# Click on excel shape passes through to VBA form

Tags: vba, excel, listbox

I have a problem I've not been able to solve. To reproduce:

In excel:

- Add a form with a listbox, multi-select, with checkboxes. On Form_Initialize, fill the listbox with items, and select them all.
- Add a macro that opens the form
- Add a shape to Excel, assign the above macro.
- Click the shape.

Now, if the form and shape are positioned correctly, what happens is that the item beneath the mouse pointer gets deselected. Strangely enough, the first item in the list gets deselected also.

If the listbox has `lst.Enabled = False`, nothing gets deselected.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. Activate is run after the click has been propagated, so I used that:

- Remove the "select all" call from `Form_Initialize`
- Add the "select all" call in `Form_Activate`
- Make the Activate-code run only once